# Best practice for global constants in Scala Application

Tags: scala, object, constants

Usually I create a "Scala Object" that keeps all my global constants. 
I have been told that it is better to use "package object" in order to keep constants.
I have never used "package object" previously so my questions are:

What are the best practices to hold constants in Scala and why?

Why do I need "package object"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You **dont** need a package object.

However it allows you to make code available at the package level without declaring another class or object.

It's a convenience.

```
package foo.bar

package object dem {
  // things here will be available in `foo.bar` package and all subpackages 
  // without the need of an import statement.
}
```

The only convention specified for constants are regarding [casing](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#constants-values-variable-and-methods). Constants should be *PascalCased*

Keep in mind that declaring constants in the package object might make them available in places where you don't want them to be available.

I leave you the [naming convention](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/09-top-level-definitions.html#package-objects) for package objects:

> The standard naming convention is to place the definition above in a file named package.scala that's located in the directory corresponding to package pp.